# I am not how they got characteristic equation from the given equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

![can someone tell me they got characteristic equation from the given recursive equation.][1]
i know how to do the rest of problem but getting characteristic equation stopped me.

The recurrence is $a_n=3a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}+5a_{n-3}$  The characteristic equation is $r^3-3r^2-4r-5=0$

Comment: Please show the equations. It appears you tried to link somewhere, but I don't see a link. We prefer questions to be self contained.

Comment: I actually uploaded a picture, it was there before i post my question but i don't what happened.

Comment: 1. a(n) = 3a(n-1) + 4a(n-2)+5(n-3).

Comment: r^3-3r^2-4r-5=0 --> it is the characteristic equation but i don't know how we got this from the above equation.  Thanks guys.

Comment: I have put the information into the question, and now believe the question is well posed.  Vote to reopen

Comment: thanks. i also need to find the roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of how to solve a linear [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).  Note that any multiple of a solution or any sum of solutions will again be a solution, so we have a vector space of solutions.  We guess that a solution is of the form $r^n$ and plug into the equation.  This gives $r^3=3r^2+4r+5$, which is exactly the characteristic equation you give.  It has three solutions, each of which gives a basis vector of the space of solutions to the original equation.  The most general solution will be a sum of three terms, each a constant multiplied by $r^n$.  Special rules apply if a root is repeated.

The cubic has one real and two imaginary roots.  They are not rational.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-3x%5E2-4x-5) can find them, presumably using Cardano's method.

Comment: how do you know it has three roots? Can you tell me how to find roots powers greater than three. thanks

Comment: Generally an $n$th degree polynomial has $n$ roots, some of which may be complex.  There is a very complicated formula to find the roots of a 4th degree polynomial, but none any higher.  Of course, some higher degree polynomials can be factored.